# How to make quora.com-like URL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For example,

http://www.quora.com/Is-getting-ripped-worth-it

As you can see, the URL for a question does not have a controller's name. It is associated with the root URL. How can I do this?

In routes.rb, I tried the following:

```
match '/:id' => "questions#show"
```

That works, but `new_question` or `edit_question` paths still generate `/questions/new(.:format)` and `/questions/:id/edit(.:format)` as URLs.

Are there any elegant solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that prevents you from doing this:

```
match '/new' => "questions#new", :as => 'new_question'
match '/:id/edit' => "questions#edit", :as => 'edit_question'
```

but you'll have to remove `:resources questions`

One elegant solution is to use the friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

You can find similar ones at slugs">http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks_slugs